How to Resolve Compatibility Issues and Build an APK for a Flutter App?
I’ve completed building a Flutter app, but I’m facing issues when trying to generate the APK for distribution. Specifically, there seem to be compatibility issues, likely related to Gradle configurations, and I could use some guidance to resolve them.
Here’s the context:

The app is built and runs fine in the development environment.
I’m    encountering errors during the APK build process (e.g., Gradle
sync    issues or dependency mismatches).

These are some of the errors I'm getting

e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/e8115fc87230851096dc74d69348a766/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.9999, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/be5917f996861d70923da160a9ee83e8/transformed/jetified-firebase-installations-18.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/com.google.firebase-firebase-installations.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/412424d0dbc20edd9edd71810011f503/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Here are some relevant sections from my code
gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-all.zip

setting.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}

android\build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22' // Or the latest compatible version
    // ... other configurations
}

and finally here are the dependencies
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8 
firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^5.3.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  better_player: ^0.0.84
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
  google_api_availability: ^5.0.0
  lecle_yoyo_player: ^0.0.8
  google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.9.0
  http: ^1.2.2

